# CSS: Breaking a Unordered List

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to break a unordered list using CSS. What i currently have is this

What i require is this

Scenario after Marcus code

Here is the html

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-content-block">
<div class="home-subheading">'Functional Requirement Documents'</div>
<ul style="list-style: none;">
<li><a  href="https://prod.us/System_Functionality/Functional_
Requirement_Documents/Agent_and_Commission">'Agent and Commission'</a></li>
<li><a similar other 21 li</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
tab-content { 
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: left;
   margin-left: 2.2em;
} 
.tab-content-block { 
   padding: 0 1em 1em .5em;
   min-width: 25%;
} 
.tab-content-block ul li {
   margin-bottom:10px;
   margin-left:-17px;
}
```

Comment: So....do you want a HTML solution? CSS solution? JavaScript solution? What are the parameters to this problem (do you have a defined set of items in the menu?)

Comment: CSS solution...Sorry

Comment: What is your CSS at the moment for the list?

Comment: .tab-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: left;
    margin-left: 2.2em;
}

.tab-content-block {
    padding: 0 1em 1em .5em;
    min-width: 25%;
}

.tab-content-block ul li {margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:-17px;}

Comment: You could use the `column-count` property. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp

Comment: Thanks Gavin, I added the column-count and it worked but facing some alignment issues as portrayed in the third image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `columns` only in the `<ul>`.

```
.tab-content-block ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
          column-count: 2;
}
```

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/hrm3tx9j/1/

Comment: Hi Marcos, i tried your output and now it is as displayed in the attached image above. Can you suggest something to align Lapse and Reinstatement Processing with Agent and  Commission?

Comment: The third image is the latest scenario after adding your code.

Comment: I think it's because the flexbox parents. You can reset with this: `.tab-content-block ul { display: block }`. I don't know if this solve your problem. Maybe you can reproduce it in a https://jsfiddle.net and then share with me that snippet, and I will solve your problem as soon as possible.

Comment: your problem is that you write the columns in the parent div, not in the <ul> (as I tell you). So change your selector to `#column ul` and it work. https://jsfiddle.net/hrm3tx9j/1/ Just read carefully the answers you get, because the solution was the first that I've write.

Comment: Hi Marcos, thanks for the update. It worked. My bad, I don't code, but trying my hands on it. Just one more question, how do i increase the space between the two? Between  Lapse and Reinstatement Processing and Agent and Commission

Comment: I was able to resolve it...i added    -webkit-column-gap: 100px; 
    -moz-column-gap: 100px; 
    column-gap: 100px;

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yeah, I answer the same. `column-gap` is the solution. You can see more about columns here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/columns and https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/

Answer (score 0):

Change the flex-direction to `column` and give `flex-wrap`

```
tab-content { 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 500px;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: left;
 margin-left: 2.2em;
}
```

It will be great if you provide a Demo link of jsFiddle or Plunkr.